# Struggling to understand how REST API Connections Work

Tags: rest-api, api

I've been tasked with connecting to our companies Salesforce API, in order to integrate our own computer system better with both Salesforce and the Financial Force account package we have.

I'm no stranger to API work but everything I'm trying keeps coming up with errors that I can't seem to resolve, where the official documentation doesn't seem particularly helpful.

Firstly, I have created a Connected App within our Salesforce Platform and generated an initial access token. I have then tried to use this token to generate a request in Postman, just to see if I can see our data, using the following endpoint from the official Salesforce Postman Collection:

```
https://[**OurPlatformName**]--[**TheSandboxName**].sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v57.0/sobjects/
```

I have attached the initially generated access token to the requested with the Authorization  type bearer but get an "Session expired or invalid" error:

[image]

After some searching, there's posts on the internet that say this is a known Postman problem  and none of the proposed fixes worked.

After that I tried Curling the endpoint...and got the same error:

[image]

At this point I'm thinking "twice is a pattern" and gave it one more go in C#. I wrote some incredibly basic code that in theory should work:

```
using var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://[**OurPlatformName**]--[**TheSandboxName**].sandbox.my.salesforce.com");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "[[**OurInitiallyGeneratedToken]]");

var response = await client.GetAsync("/services/data/v57.0/sobjects/");
    
Console.WriteLine(response);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var disposals = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(disposals);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
}
```

But once again I get the same error:

[image]

So now I'm convinced I'm doing something wrong. I suspect it's a Connected App setting on our platform but I've done seemingly everything I can, including setting the allowed IP Range to the machine I'm trying to connect from and completely relaxing the IP rules when that didn't work.

If anyone can advise me where I may be going wrong with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: can you give some more info about the type of authentication you are trying to set up in the connected app? client credentials flow works with postman when using the correct callback url

Comment: I have a strong feeling that there is certain step missing -- usually an access token starts with `00D` and on your screenshot it is `6Cel..`. Therefore an advice would be to check the process that returns it

Comment: Thank you for the response. We were not planning on using client credentials to log in, as it's our CRM software that will be interfacing directly, rather than the users within it. To that end, I was hoping to use the generated token as authentication, at least until we get have a better understanding of the data accessible to us.

Comment: @kurunve Yes I suspect you are right. I can't find any documentation saying what the step is but it certainly feels like I need to use my initially generated token to get a different/refresh token for actual use on the API.

Comment: Please ignore my previously deleted comment -- this is better link for your usecase - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_authorization_code_credentials_flow.htm&type=5

Comment: For testing, you can try using the session id from the browser to call the service and see if it is working. You will get the session id from the Browser Cookies with name `sid`.